# How to let terminal echo only graphic characters in raw&echo mode?

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal, termios

I am writing a shell. I put the terminal into raw mode and turned on ECHO flag using tcsetattr().
Now I have spent much energy repainting the editing-line to erase the mess echo like '^[[A' when user type a function key.

Is there a way to let terminal only echo visible characters?
I have checked the manual of termios carefully, but find no result.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Not as far as I know. Either you take full control by turning off echoing, or you turn on echoing and it echoes everything. The terminal driver doesn't know anything about escape sequences -- it doesn't know that `[A` are not visible if they're preceded by ESC.

Comment: The closest you can get is to turn off `ECHOCTL`, which will result in control characters being echoed as themselves rather than `^somechar`. But you almost certainly don't want that, because terminal emulators will do special things with certain sequences, such as shifting into alternate character sets and defining scrolling regions. Anyone who has accidentally `cat`ted an executable knows the pain that brings.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks. very useful. In fact, I am just watching this flag. After some experiment, I found it doesn't turns off all the function keys, including at least F5~F12, INSERT, DELTE, PGUP, PGDOWN. But several keys it turns off is very useful, Backspace, Home, End, top/down/left/right arrow, and Enter.  This let me save much effort. For the issue you pointed out , I avoid it by switch the terminal to normal state when fork a child process, like 'cat'.  The reasons i have to choose RAW&ECHO mode are that, firstly, a feature of my shell is based on monitoring the user input on time

Comment: secondly, i found the input feeling not that smoothly as 'cooked mode' unless i turned on ECHO mode. I am using readline library, and its rl_redisplay() seems poor-performance. I have to write my own rl_redisplay, and so I want the echo mechanism of tty to share my work.